# How can I use PHPUnit to make certain there are no debug print statements in the code?

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

In Symfony 4, I have an API function that returns a JSON response.  It works, and all my tests pass.  BUT, I had a print statement in the code, and so the React side of things wasn't happy with the extra print statement and blew an error.

So, I put in a test to make sure my function was returning valid json, expecting that the extra character would make that fail.

```
 $content = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();

        $json = json_decode($content);

        if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            $content = $json;
        }
```

Nope.  Still passes.  Is there any test I can do on the PHP side to make sure there are no random print statements left in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You assert that your code isn't supposed to output anything:

```
$this->expectOutputString('');
```

Otherwise, a task like this might be more suited to a code sniffer that forbids debugging functions like `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc.